# TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined, How to solve this

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-authentication

I making an express and firebase app in which I am signing up my users using firebase auth and using express routing. The code is this

I tested using POSTMAN it shows me this error
[this is the build log][1]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tshAw.png

````
const app = express();

const firebase = require('firebase/app')
require('firebase/auth')

firebase.initializeApp({
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBrrAjBnmwqwDYGZ0iAmb3CwOa2jb7aqf4",
    authDomain: "shine-online.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://shine-online.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "shine-online",
    storageBucket: "shine-online.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "74335759103",
    appId: "1:74335759103:web:f225703b6bdae0efc0baca"
})


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//routes
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World')
})

//signup route
app.post('/signup', (req, res) => {
    const newUser = {
        email: req.body.email,
        password: req.body.password,
        confirmPassword: req.body.confirmPassword,
        username: req.body.username,
    }

    
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(newUser.email,newUser.password)
        .then(data => {
            return res.status(201).json({ message: `user ${data.user.uid} signed yp suceesfully`})
         })
         .catch((err) => {
            console.error(err)
            return res.status(500).json({ error: 'something gone wrong' })
        })
        
})


app.listen(PORT, ()=> {
    console.log(`Listening on the PORT ${PORT}`)
} )```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tshAw.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that req.body is undefined, probably because the body is not parsed to JSON. Add the json parser to your project before your routes:

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

//  JSON parser middleware
app.use(express.json());

//routes
app.get('/api', (req, res) => {
    res.send('Hello World')
})
```

express.json is a middleware that will parse the body of your request to JSON.

By default, only requests with the header **Content-Type: application/json** will be parsed.

Comment: could you tell me where to input this

Comment: Sure. I've added a piece of your code so you can place it correctly. Also, you can check the docs https://expressjs.com/en/api.html